# Filter by values where key is unknown

Tags: jsonpath

In the following JSON -

```
[
  {
    "This": "TRUE",
    "is": "TRUE",
    "a": "FALSE",
    "test": "FALSE",
    "json": "TRUE"
  }
]
```

How do I get the result using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) that filters out the key<>value pair where value is "TRUE" i.e. expected output:

```
[
  {
    "This": "TRUE",
    "is": "TRUE",
    "json": "TRUE"
  }
]
```

I tried using the following query but it returned no data (null JSON) -

`$.[?(@.* == 'TRUE')]`

Is there a way to filter without specifying the key and only by determining what the value should be? I'm using a different platform to get this information and not using JavaScript or any other scripting language. Just need to determine the appropriate query that would help extract the required output.

Comment: No you cannot do this. There is no support for wildcards when matching on field names. You need to do this in code

Comment: Thanks, @tomredfern - I guess some part of me already knew that. Still a bummer though 